# @Watch & $Refs with typescript and vue-property-decorator

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js, watch

I have a question regarding watch and ref. I have a vswitch with a `v-model`. The setter action of the `v-model` takes a long long time(writes to the store and triggers a lot of updates on the DOM).

Unfortunately Vue executes the action before it renders the new value of the switch.
I want to display the input value immediately. My workaround-idea was to "watch" the switch inputValue and execute the setter action when the inputValue is changED.
How can I do this with typescript and `vue-property-decorator`?
I put a ref on my switch and tried something like this :

```
  @Watch("$refs.switch.inputValue", {
    immediate: true,
    deep: true,
  })
  change() {
    alert('value changed');
  }
```

Is this even possible with the `@watch` decorator?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use @Watch to watch $refs, because properties of [$refs aren't reactive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements). You'd better use events. You are probably using [Vuetify's v-switch](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selection-controls/). You could use its change-event and listen to it:

```
<v-switch @change="valueChanged()"/>
```

...

```
valueChanged() {
  // handle change event
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, this doesn't work out(it was, of course, the first thing I tried...), because the change event is called before the switch changes on the DOM. I also tried to use Vue.nextTick but this doesn't work out as well. It seems to me, that there is no solution with vue. I ended up using the beautiful vuetify switch loading spinner.